# sendEmail function: How to show the account name as sender not the email prefix

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm sending emails using `sendEmail` function from google sheets and the emails arrive showing the sender as the prefix of my email address (before the @ sign) instead of my `gsuite` account name, as they do when sending an email manually. Is there a way to change the from field?

```
function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var subject = sheet2.getRange(2, 1).getValue();
  var n = sheet1.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 2; i < n + 1; i++) {
    var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    var name = sheet1.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    var message = sheet2.getRange(2, 2).getValue();

    message = message.replace("<name>", name);
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to set `From` of the header from `From: ###@gmail.com` to `From: sample name <###@gmail.com>` using `MailApp.sendEmail`, how about modifying as follows?

#### From:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
```

#### To:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {name: "sample name"});
```

or

```
MailApp.sendEmail({to: emailAddress,subject: subject,body: message,name: "sample name"});
```

#### Note:

- This modification supposes that your script except for `MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message)` works.
- If I misunderstood your goal, can you provide the result value you expect? By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### Reference:

- [Class MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)

Comment: Hi Tanaike. Thank you, your suggestion worked adding {name:"myname"} to the sendEmail function.

Comment: @Thomas Jackson Thank you for your response.